# Beamer: Adding bullets to Warsaw paletter

Tags: beamer, formatting, lists, themes

Is there a way to add bullets, as they are desplayed in list enviroments, in the 'list' shown in the paletter, as I believe it is called, of the Warsaw theme?

Since I am not sure If I have explained the question correctly, I'll add a (poor quality) graphical representation of it:

[image]

Somewhat like this.

This might be trivial in the end but I had trouble forming the question correctly when searching for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you want to add bullet for every section, subsection in the headline.

You can do it with a minimal change in the definition of `\insertsectionnavigation` and `\insertsubsectionnavigation`

The definitions of both commands in `beamerbasenavigation.sty` are:

```
\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \vskip0.5625ex%
     \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
       \ifnum##5=\c@part%
       \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
       \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
         \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             \hskip0.3cm%
             \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}%
             \else%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}%
             \fi\hskip0.3cm}}}%
       \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
       \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
     \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}
```

and

```
\def\insertsubsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vskip0.5625ex%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0%
      \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}%
      \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{\ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section%
        \ifnum##2>\beamer@currentsubsection%
        \beamer@currentsubsection=##2%
        \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##2}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##6}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\beamer@link(##4){%
            \hbox to #1{\hskip0.3cm%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}}%
              \fi\hfil\hskip0.3cm}}}%
        \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
        \box\beamer@tempbox\fi\fi\fi}%
      \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}\hfil}}}
```

Just add your bullet in the definition of `\insertsectionhead` and `\insertsubsectionhead`

**An example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}    

\makeatletter
\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \vskip0.5625ex%
     \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
       \ifnum##5=\c@part%
       \def\insertsectionhead{$\circ$ ##2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
       \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
         \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             \hskip0.3cm%
             \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}%
             \else%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}%
             \fi\hskip0.3cm}}}%
       \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
       \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
     \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}

\def\insertsubsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vskip0.5625ex%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0%
      \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}%
      \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{\ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section%
        \ifnum##2>\beamer@currentsubsection%
        \beamer@currentsubsection=##2%
        \def\insertsubsectionhead{$\circ$ ##5}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##2}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##6}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\beamer@link(##4){%
            \hbox to #1{\hskip0.3cm%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}}%
              \fi\hfil\hskip0.3cm}}}%
        \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
        \box\beamer@tempbox\fi\fi\fi}%
      \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}\hfil}}}     

\makeatother     


\begin{document}

\section{section one}
\subsection{subsection one}
\begin{frame}
hello world
\end{frame}
\section{section two}
\begin{frame}
hello world too
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

For bullet only with current section and current subsection

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}    

\makeatletter
\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \vskip0.5625ex%
     \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
       \ifnum##5=\c@part%
       \def\insertsectionhead{\ifnum\c@section=##1{$\circ$}\fi\ ##2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
       \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
         \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             \hskip0.3cm%
             \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}%
             \else%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}%
             \fi\hskip0.3cm}}}%
       \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
       \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
     \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}

\def\insertsubsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vskip0.5625ex%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0%
      \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}%
      \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{\ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section%
        \ifnum##2>\beamer@currentsubsection%
        \beamer@currentsubsection=##2%
        \def\insertsubsectionhead{\ifnum\c@subsection=##2{$\circ$}\fi\ ##5}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##2}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##6}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\beamer@link(##4){%
            \hbox to #1{\hskip0.3cm%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}}%
              \fi\hfil\hskip0.3cm}}}%
        \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
        \box\beamer@tempbox\fi\fi\fi}%
      \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}\hfil}}}     

\makeatother     


\begin{document}

\section{section one}
\subsection{subsection one}
\begin{frame}
hello world
\end{frame}
\section{section two}
\begin{frame}
hello world too
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Close, I just need the circle to appear only for the **curent** section and **current** subsection.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Why those complicated redefinitions? Isn't 
`\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hfill$\circ$~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}{\insertsubsectionhead\hfill}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}{$\circ$~\insertsubsectionhead\hfill}` enough?

Comment: Elegant method,  can you post it  as answer?